# how to make Creating a Tilted Animation Popup with Dynamic Color Change

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I want an animation popup like the one shown in the image below. An example is as follows: on page 1, there is a DOM element that appears in the form of a popup, and I want it to animate as follows. The part I'm most concerned about is how to create the animation where it tilts when the center line is vertical, and the color of the corresponding area is reflected until it becomes horizontal. If you have an example like the one above, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share it. Alternatively, if you could provide example code or even just some guidance on how to create it, that would be very helpful.enter image description here

please help me,,,

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. Try always to post a [mcve] of your best code you got after an extensive research that presents the current problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve the desired effect is to use CSS's `clip-path` `polygon()` function on a `::before` and a 180degrees rotated `::after` pseudo element. Animate using `animation` keyframes:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.item::before,
.item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: clip 1.4s linear forwards;
}

.item::before {
  background: #feaa00;
}

.item::after {
  background: #b143d5;
  rotate: 180deg;
}

@keyframes clip {
  0% { /* Line bottom */
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  25% { /* Half vertical */
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  50% { /* Diagonal */
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  50.01% { /* (Immediate corner jump) */
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 100%);
  } 
  75% { /* Half horizontal */
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
  }
  100% { /* Line top */  
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```